# Reusing existing Assets

Tags: mesh, rigging

Just a quick question here that I’m positive you can help with. I’m wondering what the suggested work flow is to reusing some of my clothing assets or free license clothing pieces that are in an A pose on say Sketchfab.

So far I’ve tried the following:

- metarigging the clothing and moving into place, then adjusting with sculpting and edit mode to better fit the model
- Using the pose brush with Face sets on the UV seams followed by some clean up

I’m just wondering if there is a better solution? For reference it’s just still renders I am trying to achieve (no animation )

Sorry if I did not provide enough detail. Please advise on any other information you need. The model in question is basically a male mannequin with the legs and hands removed so just upper torso with arms by his sides. I have him rigged to put him in an A or T pose to place the clothing then I move into place